# Portable Generator with Manual Transfer Switch Troubleshooting

Tags: electrical, generator, transfer-switch

When I hook up a generator to my house via a transfer switch it does one of the following:

- Trips the main breaker on the generator immediately.  It does this when the generator is neutral bonded.
- Or, after floating the neutral, it burned up an AC adapter/transformer that was plugged into an outlet on the only circuit I tested.  It made a pop sound and then the AC adapter smelled like smoke after maybe 15-30 seconds of being pluggeg in.

I think the generator needs to have the neutral floated based on [this](http://www.reliancecontrols.com/Support.aspx?faq#faq_PT_22) FAQ from the transfer switch manufacturer.

The generator seems to be putting out the correct voltage.  This is what I'm measuring from the 50amp outlet with no load:

- Hot to hot outputs 245V
- Either hot to neutral outputs 120V
- Either hot to ground outputs 120V
- Neutral to ground outputs 0V

The transfer switch was professionally installed.  Pulling off the main breaker panel cover, I see that the ground and neutral both appear to correctly be connected to the neutral bar.  Everything has been working fine when hooked up to utility power.  The generator does have a high THD of up to 27%.

**Setup**

- Generator: [Westinghouse 9500 DF](https://westinghouseoutdoorpower.com/products/wgen9500df-generator-dual-fuel)
- Cable: NEMA 14-50P to CS6364, 10
  ft.  Similar to [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078HJQY4P) one.
- Transfer Switch: Reliance Pro Trans 2
  10 circuit

Would it be safe to hook the generator back to the house with the neutral floated and let the power flow to a 15 amp circuit so I can test the voltage output of an outlet to verify it's 120V?  Or would I risk damaging the transfer switch, wiring, breaker, etc?

How can I troubleshoot further?

Comment: When turning on the transfer switch, are all the house breakers on or off?

Comment: "I see that the ground and neutral both appear to correctly be connected to the neutral bar." Please confirm that the generator is connected to the main (only) panel in the house, not a sub panel.

Comment: @crip659, the transfer switch doesn't have a single "On/off". It has a throw switch by circuit and can change from "line", "off", or "generator" power.  I switched a single circuit to "generator" power.  All breakers are on.

Comment: @FreeMan, yes, the transfer switch is connected to the main house panel, not a sub panel.

Comment: Floating the neutral is a safety thing should have nothing to do with the issue, the transfer switch if wired properly needs the breakers on the switch only affects the output of each circuit. My guess is that you have a multi wire or tandem breaker going to the wrong leg creating the short, this could happen if a pro was not paying attention to the legs , this is one reason other than the cost I do not like these transfer switches.

Comment: @EdBeal, my understanding, based on the FAQ I linked, is that floating the neutral is required to work with a 2 pole transfer switch.  Otherwise, the circuit would have two paths to ground.  The behavior is different when the neutral is floated vs bonded.  I did not verify every circuit was wired correctly, but did follow the wires of  the one circuit I was testing, which *seemed* to be wired correctly.  I also checked that I get 120V between the main panel breaker and the neutral bar when it's on utility power for that circuit.  Thanks to you and everyone else for weighing in!

Comment: You are correct. but it will not cause an overload , I asked as I do this for a living not just an internet electrician, I had a similar issue with a customer’s install where a tandem or seperate l1,l2 or there was a circuit that was field tied 2 breakers on 1 pole it worked fine until load was turned on, it’s been over 20 years when I used to use those disconnects and i was trying to remember I had the same problem it was a bugger to find, I believe it was a field tie on 2 circuits that were on the same leg, on the transfer switch they were on L1/L2 and that created a dead short.

Comment: Hm, checked the manual, there's no GFCI protection on the large outputs so it sounds like it's a miswiring issue in the connecting cable or transfer switch.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use one of those hinky "select circuit" transfer switches, instead of a transfer subpanel?  Also, do you ever want to use your generator for portable /worksite duty?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine, I think it can still trip the main breaker even if the 50amp isn't GFCI protected.  Which would make sense with the behavior I'm seeing.  The electrician did verify (via visual inspection) the wiring in the extension cable is correct.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, no I will only ever use this generator for house backup.

Comment: You might put all the switches in generator mode and first verify there is no voltage (generator not connected) then measure L1 to L2 with an ohm meter a incandescent bulb can create a dead short (looks that way to a dc ohm meter) you may have what I tried to describe, the gen works fine, your power from the utility is fine, when transferring to generator is the problem if everything is not on the same leg as it was a issue in the field may show up as a short.

Comment: Thanks again for chiming in @EdBeal and everyone. It turns out the neutral wire in the outlet the generator plugs into was not seated properly.  After fixing, I re-grounded the neutral in the generator and everything is working properly.